# catching exception of googlemaps for ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google maps for reverse GEO coding.

When I manually kill the app I get the "crash":

```
-[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:]
Background execution would crash in this scenario
```

The solution by google is:

```
You can catch this exception, and attempt re-initialize GMSServices once you have come to the foreground.
```

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7716

I have no problem doing it, the code is about to die anyway. The thing is that I can't find `GMSBackgroundAppException` anywhere in the framework (I need an h file it resides in order to catch it)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the bug report for this on Google's forums.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7716)

`GMSBackgroundAppException` isn't public and can't be caught, as you've found. I'd suggest following the advice given in that thread about snapshotting your map view when it's going into the background, which will probably avoid this issue in the first place.

Comment: yeah... but the thing is I have no map view. I run `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:XXX]` on `appdelegate` and then just use `[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:self.location completionHandler: ^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {`
have no object to snapshot...

Comment: Ha! In that case, it sounds like their backgrounding check is too aggressive and you should report that as a bug.